# Cannot linking date start and date end in datetimepicker tempus dominus

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I cannot linking date start and date end using tempus dominus picker. I already create code as instruction in its website but it doesn't work.

This is my HTML and Jquery in one file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="fragment/head :: headFragment"/>
<head>
     <style>
    

    html, body, .content-page {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #wrapper, .content-page {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .content {
        overflow: auto;
        /*padding-bottom: 38.5667px; !* this needs to be bigger than footer height*!*/
        padding: 20px 5px 124px 5px !important;
    }

    footer {
        z-index: 1;
        /*margin-top: -38.5667px;*/
        position: static;
    }
        </style>
</head>
<body class="fixed-left">
<!-- Begin page -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div th:replace="fragment/topbar :: topBarFragment"/>

    <div th:replace="fragment/leftsidebar :: leftSideBarFragment"/>

    <div class="content-page">
        <!-- Start content -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Page-Title -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4 class="page-title">Cek MO ISAT</h4>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-box">


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group" id="divShortCode">
                                <label>Shortcode: </label>
                                <br/>

                                <select class="form-control" id="shortcode">
                                    <option value="93230">93230</option>
                                    <option value="99386">99386</option>
                                    <!--                                    <option value="99386 partner">99386 Partner</option>-->
                                    <option value="Ximpay">XIMPAY</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4" id="divinputMsisdn">
                            <div class="form-group" id="groupinputMsisdn"><label>MSISDN<span
                                    class="text-danger">*</span></label><br/><input class="form-control"
                                                                                    id="inputMsisdn" required="true"
                                                                                    placeholder="Format No HP : 6281259xxxxx"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Start Date</label><br/>

                                <div class="input-group date" id="divDateStart" data-target-input="nearest" >
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#divDateStart" />
                                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#divDateStart" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>End Date</label><br/>

                                <div class="input-group date" id="divDateEnd" data-target-input="nearest" >
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#divDateEnd" />
                                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#divDateEnd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="viewButton" disabled="">View</button>
                </div>

                <!--Table-->
                <div class="card-box" hidden="hidden" id="listhasil">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                                <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title">List MO</h4>

                                <p class="text-muted font-14 m-b-30"></p>
                                <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
                                       width="100%"></table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end row -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container -->
        </div>
        <!-- content -->

        <!--Loading-->
        <div class="modal1Class modal-backdrop fade show object-hide"></div>
        <div class="modal2Class modal fade show object-hide" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
             role="dialog"
             style="padding-top: 15%; overflow-y: visible; padding-right: 17px; display: block;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-m">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title" style="margin:0;">Loading</h4></div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Loading-->
        <footer th:replace="fragment/footer :: footerFragment"/>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- END wrapper -->

<block th:replace="fragment/javascript :: javaScriptFragment"/>
<script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/dialog.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/ellipsis.js}"></script>


<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    // jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');
    // function changeFunc() {
    //     var tgl_awal = $("#tglawal").val();
    //     var dateawal = new Date(tgl_awal);
    //     var date2 = new Date();
    //     date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //     if (dateawal.getTime() === date2.getTime()) {
    //         document.getElementById("divtglakhir").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    //     }
    //     else {
    //         document.getElementById("divtglakhir").removeAttribute("hidden");
    //     }
    // }
    //
    // var date = new Date();
    // date.setDate(date.getDate() - 4);
    $(function () {

        $("#divDateStart").datetimepicker();
        $("#divDateEnd").datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#divDateStart").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $("#divDateEnd").datetimepicker('minDate', e.date);
        });
        $("#divDateEnd").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $("#divDateStart").datetimepicker('maxDate', e.date);
        });
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is Javascript Fragment to insert plugin

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<block th:fragment="javaScriptFragment">
    <script>
        var resizefunc = [];
    </script>



    <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/detect.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/fastclick.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.blockUI.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/waves.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/wow.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js}"></script>

    <!--WaitingDialog-->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/bootstrap-waitingfor.js}"></script>


    <!-- Plugin  -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/moment/moment.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/clockpicker/js/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js}"></script>

    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/morris/morris.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/raphael/raphael-min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.js}"></script>




    <!-- Required datatable js -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- Buttons examples -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/jszip.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/pdfmake.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/vfs_fonts.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/buttons.print.min.js}"></script>

    <!-- Key Tables -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.keyTable.min.js}"></script>

    <!-- Responsive examples -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.responsive.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>

    <!-- Selection table -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.select.min.js}"></script>

    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/notifyjs/js/notify.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/plugins/notifications/notify-metro.js}"></script>


    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.core.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/jquery.app.js}"></script>

    <script th:if="${page == 'checkboxDatatable'}" th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:if="${page == 'checkboxDatatable'}"
            th:src="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js}"></script>

    <!--<script th:src="@{/resources/assets/pages/jquery.dashboard.js}"></script>-->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/pages/jquery.form-pickers.init.js}"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.counter').counterUp({
                delay: 100,
                time: 1200
            });

            $(".knob").knob();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Default Datatable
            $('#datatable').DataTable();

            // Key Tables

            $('#key-table').DataTable({
                keys: true
            });

            // Responsive Datatable
            $('#responsive-datatable').DataTable();

            // Multi Selection Datatable
            $('#selection-datatable').DataTable({
                select: {
                    style: 'multi'
                }
            });
        } );
    </script>
</block>
</html>
```

And this is head fragment. I insert the datetimepicker plugin here.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="headFragment">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Triyakom Tools"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Triyakom"/>

    <!-- Favicon and Title -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/resources/assets/images/favicon.ico}"/>
    <title>CMS Monitoring Triyakom</title>

    <!--Morris Chart CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/resources/plugins/morris/morris.css}"/>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Responsive datatable examples -->
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Multi Item Selection examples -->
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/select.bootstrap4.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/clockpicker/css/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css}" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>

    <link th:href="@{/resources/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/assets/css/icons.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/assets/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link th:if="${page == 'checkboxDatatable'}"
          th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:if="${page == 'checkboxDatatable'}" th:href="@{/resources/plugins/datatables/dataTables.checkboxes.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script th:src="@{/resources/assets/js/modernizr.min.js}"></script>

    <link th:href="@{/resources/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <style>
        th, td {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        /*.object-hide {*/
        /*    display: none;*/
        /*}*/

        /*html, body, .content-page {*/
        /*    height: 100%;*/
        /*}*/

        /*#wrapper, .content-page {*/
        /*    min-height: 100%;*/
        /*}*/

        /*.content {*/
        /*    !*overflow: auto;*!*/
        /*    padding-bottom: 38.5667px; !* this needs to be bigger than footer height*!*/
        /*}*/

        /*footer {*/
        /*    z-index: 1;*/
        /*    margin-top: -38.5667px;*/
        /*    position: static;*/
        /*}*/
    </style>
</head>
</html>
```